# How to reach the content of a trackViewUrl via iTunes Search API?

Tags: php, json, api, itunes, podcast

I'm trying to list audio/video preview URLS of a podcast show, for example: Solid Steel.

I have [this result](https://itunes.apple.com/search?entity=podcast&media=podcast&term=solid%20steel) and i can get the URL (trackViewUrl node) that i want to parse. I can parse that with file_get_contents and simple_html_dom class. But it's too slow. I want to do this with JSON/JS way.

I wonder if it's possible to reach the content of the trackViewUrl with a JSON request via [iTunes Search API](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podcasts are unique in that they don't have a (90sec or 30sec) preview on the store - the preview functionality just plays the entire episode.

What you want to do with the JSON result you just got from iTunes is parse the "feedUrl" from the results.  When you crawl the feed of the podcast directly you can get the audio URL for each episode.

iTunes doesn't host the content for podcasts like they do for songs.  The podcast owner is responsible for hosting and pointing their feed to iTunes.  Any broken audio links or issues with the feedUrl will be the responsibility of the podcast owner.

Comment: Yes, reach the entire episode is what i want. I think feedUrl paramater is not reliable. Because the content of the feed can corrupted or entirely down sometimes. I believe iTunes read and collect xml feeds data in their database. For example: Bleep Podcast have this feed: http://podcast.bleep.com/weekly_podcast_itunes.xml The feed is corrupted right now as you can see. But iTunes still list their episodes correctly. So i can trust iTunes database rather than feedUrl.

Comment: Interesting that you are having problems with that feed - I have not had any problems crawling that same feed both at the time I responded and just now.
iTunes will crawl the feed and save it to cache for display on the store but the feeds are constantly crawled for updates.  You should do the same.